# How do I import groups from graphml file? (networkx -> cytoscape)

Tags: networkx, cytoscape

I'm trying to bring networkx data into cytoscape. I'm using graphml and that part is fine, but I have an attribute parent=node_name that I want to establish a group with. I cannot find out how to map this in cytoscape. Any ideas on how to automatically create groups in cytoscape?

Example:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node("server1")
G.add_node("server1_port1", parent="server1")
G.add_node("server1_port2", parent="server1")
G.add_node("server2")
G.add_node("server2_port1", parent="server2)
G.add_node("server2_port2", parent="server2)
G.add_edge("server1_port1", "server2_port1")
nx.write_graphml(G, "output.graphml")
```

It should look something like this:

```
+-----------------+
|    server1      |
|                 |
| {port1} {port2} |
|    ~            |
|    |            |
+----|------------+
     |
+----|------------+
|    server2      |
|    |            |
|    ~            |
| {port1} {port2} |
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, our GraphML reader doesn't support groups -- I can think of ways to do this semi-automatically, but I'm not sure that's what you want.  What you would need to do is to add an attribute to each of your nodes (e.g. "parent") and then create the groups using that attribute (the setsApp will help you do that).  Once you've created the groups, use the Compound Node visualization to get the look you want.

-- scooter